# for comprehension with tuple, withFilter is not a member error

Tags: scala

The following code snippet

```
import util.control.TailCalls._
for {(num, ch) <- done((3, '3'))
} yield num
```

fails to compile with error message:

> value withFilter is not a member of util.control.TailCalls.TailRec[(Int, Char)]

I am using Scala 2.12.7. How to avoid this error? (IntelliJ Idea 18.3.1 with Scala plugin v2018.3.4 does not show error.)

Answer (score 4):

To avoid the call to `withFilter` and keep the current syntax, it helps if a compiler plugin is used to treat for comprehensions differently. An option is using [better-monadic-for](https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for).

Adding this to the build.sbt file should make the code in the question compile:

```
addCompilerPlugin("com.olegpy" %% "better-monadic-for" % "0.3.0-M4")
```

(Though it has other -usually positive- effects too, please check its documentation.)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is implementing `withFilter` with an extension method, for example like this (and having it in scope at usage site):

```
  implicit class TailCallsExtension[A](t: TailRec[A]) {
    def withFilter(pred: A => Boolean): TailRec[A] = t.flatMap(a => if (pred(a)) t else done(a))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly there is no filtering in the code, but actually the pattern match in Scala for comprehensions (before `<-`) are translated as a call to `withFilter`. `TailCalls` does not support `withFilter`, so this will not compile. The following rewrite compiles though:

```
import util.control.TailCalls._
done((3, '3')).map{ case (num, ch) => num}
```